# Is it possible to build a zip-distribution that would contain a jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to produce a binary zip distribution of my project that would contain an uber jar and a set of scripts. Right now, I am using two descritors, first one for the uber jar, and the second for the zip that contains the uberjar + extra scripts and documentation. The problem is that both of these get deployed to maven repo, while I don't actually need the uberjar, only the distro. Is there any way to either:

- create the distro using one descriptor or
- avoid the uberjar being deployed?

*Edit: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559388/maven-avoid-deploying-project-package-implied-artifact-during-standard-build-lif) regarding part 2, but perhaps there is an easier way to do it...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way *is* to create the uberjar in one module (set the [`skip`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip) optional parameter in the maven-deploy-plugin configuration to bypass it during `deploy`) and to create the zip distribution in another module (using a dependency on the previously created assembly  as described in [Assembling Assemblies via Assembly Dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-assembling-via-depend.html)). And that's very close to what you already have which is good news.