# How to selectively upload artifacts to a nexus repo in a multi module maven project

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a mutimodule project building wars, jars etc.

project A
|
|
---------sub-proj-A1
|              |
|              -------pom.xml
---------sub-proj-A2
!              |
|              -------pom.xml
---------sub-proj-A3
|              |
|              -------pom.xml
---------sub-proj-A4
|              |
|              -------pom.xml
---------sub-proj-A5
|              |
|              -------pom.xml
---------pom.xml

This would be built using mvn clean deploy (project A is a multimodule project).
The problem is when it comes to upload (deploy), only proj-A2 & proj-A3 need to be uploaded to the nexus repo.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559388/maven-avoid-deploying-project-package-implied-artifact-during-standard-build-li

Answer (score 4):

Ensure the modules are defined in your project.  Eg. parent pom you would put something like

```
<modules>
<module>sub-proj-A1</module>
.. n entries
<module>sub-proj-An</module>
</modules>
```

Then when you want to run the deploy you can run mvn deploy -pl proj-A2 proj-A3

Sources:
Maven Modules: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

A working example can be seen in the struts2 pom here: https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: ctwomey1, the SVN Apache example link you've provided is broken. Could you please update it?

Comment: aribeiro I updated it to their latest github release.  I'm sure there are far more relevant examples now a days (considering this answer is 4 years old now)

Comment: You're absolutely right, just wanted to make you aware of the situation, nothing else ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [skip](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html#skip) feature of the Deploy plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```